# Which one of the problems belong to P?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

> Suppose $P\neq NP$. The following problem can be solved
> in polynomial time?
>
> - Given natural number $n$ and positive real numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ and $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$. The goal is to find
>   $I\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that $\sum_{i\in I}b_i$ maximized and
>   $\sum_{i\in I}a_i\leq 5$.

But I have no idea about it. Any help will be appreciated and I prefer to get some hints, not the complete solution.

Comment: If you only want to ask about the first problem, I suggest that you [edit] your question to ask only about the first problem.  There is no need to list a problem that you are not asking about and where you already know the answer.  Also, please add a credit to the original source that you are copying from, as per https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Where you write "Give", do you mean "Given"?  How are the real numbers represented?  $P,NP$ relate to problems on bits, not real numbers.

Comment: Oh, it looks like the question has already been answered previously.  I've marked it as a duplicate of the prior question, where you should be able to find an answer to the question.

Comment: What condition for the a_i would make it polynomial time?

Comment: @gnasher729 I edit it. I think it's polynomial due to this problem is knapsack and due to  $W=O(1)$ the running time will be $O(n)$ with dynamic programming.